# Mysql regexp_replace is hanging on

Tags: mysql, regex

I have to replace every char in varchar column by regex. So I try to do

> SELECT mysql.regexp_replace("varchar_column", '.', '*') FROM
>   varchar_table;

This statement is hanging on and then terminated by timeout. 
The same result for

> SELECT mysql.regexp_replace('qwerty', '.', '*') FROM dual;

No errors and I have no idea what's happening.

Comment: What are you trying to replace exactly? Because this is going to replace literally every character with `*` for the given subject.

Comment: Is `mysql.regexp_replace` a typo (instead of just `regexp_replace`) or did you add your own function that may simply not work? (e.g.: are you using mariadb or not / are you using a linux distribution or not)? The default mariadb function would be called without `mysql` infront of the command.

Comment: @Solarflare                                                                   
mysql.regexp_replace definitely is not a typo. This function exists.

Comment: @ctwheels  Yes. I'm trying to replace every char with *

Comment: In this case, this function is no standard function. So the problem is likely the function itself, and it's hard to tell what went wrong there from the information in your question. It's probably some udf like [this](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp), and it may help to simply update/reinstall it. You could add some more information, e.g. if you are on shared hosting (and/or someone else installed it), if it worked before (or works with other parameters), your os and mysql version, and `show create function mysql.regexp_replace`. Also check for errors in your mysql.err-log file.